# Django Filebrowser, broken data stream when reading image file

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, file-browser

I'm doing a website for my friend. I tried to use django-filebrowser, which I have been using for a long time with no problems. 
I've got a django-grappelli installed for it and latest Pillow.

Situation look like this: I'm uploading small image and it appears in my filebrowser popup. The problem starts with bigger images. Right after upload, when I click to view all images, I'm getting an error which is saying: `broken data stream when reading image file`
Everything set up localy is working perfectly, but when I try to run it on my production server, filebrowser falls appart.

Im posting here an image with error and full log error.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiAC6.png]

external image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiAC6.png
besides that here is a full raw log:
http://pastebin.com/7rzKYPHF

I was trying to change chmod settings, install another versions of grappelli, filebrowser and pillow. Also I've tried to include various numbers of settings in my settings.py file. But nothing was successful. My guess is that something is wrong with creating a django thumbnail or something.

This is the first time I'm occuring this error.

Any help is appreciated.

Best wishes
SEB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the solution. I knew something was wrong with system libraries, because this problem occured on 2 servers. Unfortunetely I couldn`t access admin rights because it was not my VPS, just rented hosting with no admin rights.

The problem was with libjpeg in version 6.8. Everything works fine from version 8, after recompiling virtualenviroment.

Best wishes !